# Stack Overflow seems quite slow to me lately

Tags: support

**Update 16/02/2012**: Haven't seen this all day. Not a blip, or at least, nothing to remark on.

---

The past week or two, SO's been really quite slow at times, really impacting at least my ability to contribute to the site. Is this a known issue being addressed? Are others running into it? If not, I'll put it down to my route to the site having issues for whatever reason.

Specifically:

- I just clicked a question, and the request `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291843/cloning-elements-keeping-select-values` took 14.9 seconds, 14.57 of which was "waiting," 331ms being "receiving". (The ancillary stuff after the request for that URL was very quick.) More typical times for me are that the main question request takes a third of a second or less, in total.
- I've also recently been getting timeouts when clicking question, nothing comes up at all.
- Clicking my inbox, I'll get a long delay (sometimes markedly long). One example I measured was fairly short, but still `http://stackoverflow.com/inbox/genuwine?_=1329301825268` took more than two full seconds to load (whereas normally in my experience it's nearly instantaneous).
- I'll add a comment and see the progress dots for several seconds before it gets added, sometimes even getting the orange box saying a problem occurred.
- I'll click to edit something and, again, see the progress dots for several seconds (sometimes quite a few) before the editing interface appears.

My rough, unscientific sense (not having monitored with the console open, but I am now so I can be specific about what URLs are being slow to load) is that it's the dynamic content server rather than the static stuff. I've had issues with the static stuff in the past (hit refresh and the CSS doesn't load, that kind of thing; usually only for brief periods of time), but these symptoms are different.

Comment: Please provide more information, e.g. which of the page resources aren't loading quickly. I sometimes have issues with two specific files provided from the CDN.

Comment: @DanielBeck: It's general, but I'll update with specifics as I notice them.

Comment: You use the word "people", implying that it is not only you, but more people: that would mean you have more information. If that's not what you mean, wouldn't it be better to say "me" instead of "people"?

Comment: @Nanne: I've changed it. Could just be me, I suppose.

Comment: Check :) , for added information//debugging: I haven't noticed anything outoftheordinary from here (location: netherlands) the last few days.

Comment: I saw this on Friday and Jeff reported a similar complaint on the weekend, I looked through logs and haproxy claims stuff is good , so it must be happening prior to it being routed to our haproxy box

Comment: I thought I had similar problems, but figured it was probably the work proxy...

Comment: @Benjol: No proxies here. (Well, just Plus.net's.)

Comment: I've witnessed a drastic slowdown, but only on the /review page when it's filtered for "Low-quality posts" (but not the other filters). I just figured that it was because there are A LOT of posts that fit that category...

Comment: I've witnessed some slowdowns too exactly as you described

Comment: I have been seeing this for the last few days.. I assumed it was my work connection (it blows bigtime) however at home today the site is crawling on FIOS.